# How to display "No Items" content in ComboBox if target ItemsSource is null?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am trying to create a Combobox with updatable collection. Than I would to display special content inside combobox if collection which binding to combobox in null.

I had try to set `TargetNullValue` parameter but it's display content not as I expected.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue='No Items'}"/>
```

What I Have Now

[image: What I have now]

What I Expect

[image: What I expect]

Comment: The combobox does as designed: show every item of a collection. A string is a collection of char … get the point? ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo Yes but maybe there is should be simple way how to present a one string as one Item of collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may replace the ComboBox's Template when it has no items, e.g. with a TextBlock or any other visual element.

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                                <TextBlock Text="No Items"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Although this method hides the original template, it is better because it does not create another collection and does not change the selected item

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I can’t check it myself - I don’t have a computer “at hand”):

```xml
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="noItems">
            <sys:String>No Items</sys:String>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
  
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TergetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MyCollection}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyCollection.Count}"
                             Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{DynamicResource noItems}"/>
                    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    <ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Or such variant for TargetNullValue:

```xml
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Path="MyCollection">
            <Binding.TargetNullValue>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <sys:String>No Items</sys:String>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </Binding.TargetNullValue>
        </Binding>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```